# ThoMoNetworking Library: getting error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: objective-c, communication, interprocess

I have a problem with the library ThoMoNetworking that I have included in my project for interprocess communication. In the `TCPConnection` class and in the method `close` there is

```
[inStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

I'm getting

```
:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

The inStream is not empty, nor is the object `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]`.